# Can you specify how an argument in an attribute is resolved?

Tags: c#, .net

If I have classes like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public string MyProperty {get; set;}
}

public class ClassB
{

   public ClassA ClassA {get; set;}

   [MyAttribute(nameof(ClassA.MyProperty))]
   public void MyMethod()
   {
   }

}

public sealed class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
   public string MyProperty {get; private set;}

   public MyAttribute(string myProperty)
   {
      MyProperty = myProperty;
   }
}
```

Then the `ClassA` in `[MyAttribute(nameof(ClassA.MyProperty))]` is resolved to the property and not the class resulting in a compile time error (`An object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property 'ClassB.ClassA'`). If I renamed the property then it would be resolved to the class and it works.

Is it possible to specify that I want it to resolve to the class without having to rename the property?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not really understanding. What does "resolve" mean? Are you looking for `typeof(ClassA)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct terminology is for what the compiler interprets the word to be. Maybe "translate" is better?

If I wrote `new ClassA()` the compiler knows "ClassA" means the class.

If inside `ClassB` I wrote `this.ClassA` it knows I mean the property.

But in my question it is ambiguous and it decides to go with the property.

My question is fairly abstract but `typeof(ClassA) `is not the same thing as referring to the class itself.

Comment: Are you wanting to refer to the type `ClassA` or the property `ClassA`?

Comment: Please provide valid, complete code.  Both classes are missing the `class` keyword, `[MyAttribute(ClassA)]` doesn't "resolve" to anything but a compiler error, and the definition of `MyAttribute` is not provided.  Or are you asking why the absence of a `ClassA` property changes the compiler error on `[MyAttribute(ClassA)]` from `"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ClassB.ClassA'"` to `"'ClassA' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"`?

Comment: I'm still not really understanding what you want here. What do you mean "resolved to the property and not the class"? What does "resolving to the class" mean? What does that provide you with?

Comment: The updated code is much more clear.  What namespace is this all defined in?  `[MyAttribute(nameof(MyNamespace.ClassA.MyProperty))]` is what you want.

Comment: Ok. Apologies. I over generalised my question. I have updated it now, hopefully it is clearer and a proper minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @BACON
Ahhh thankyou. Seems pretty obvious now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment I'm not finding a duplicate where a property is "hiding" a class of the same name, but assuming the code in the question is defined in a `namespace` named `MyNamespace`, you just need to specify the property's [fully-qualified name](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#fully-qualified-names)...

```cs
[MyAttribute(nameof(MyNamespace.ClassA.MyProperty))]
public void MyMethod()
{
}
```

Note that [`nameof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) returns the same name for an entity regardless of how you qualify it.  For example, at the end of the following `Main()` method...

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        object MyProperty { get; set; }

        static void Main()
        {
            string name1 = nameof(MyNamespace.MyClass.MyProperty);
            string name2 = nameof(MyClass.MyProperty);
            string name3 = nameof(MyProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

...the variables `name1`, `name2`, and `name3` will all contain `"MyProperty"`.